# Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled when creating npm package of a react component

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I am working on a npm package from a React component ,
when I try to consume the package for testing I get the following error

> Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled

Note: I don't have this error on the package project itself it only shows when I import it into a testing project.

this is what I have in my .babelrc in the package project

```
{
   "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

my package.json file for the package

```
{
  "name": "@myname/core",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Now you can make cool animation popups/alerts",
  "main": "./build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "build": "webpack"
  },
  "repository": {
   "type": "git",
   "url": "https://github.com/Uttam146/uttam_rawat-popups"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "myname",
 "license": "MIT",
 "devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
  "css-loader": "^3.3.0",
  "style-loader": "^1.0.1",
  "webpack": "^5.88.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

my src/index.js file is as following

```
import React from "react";

function Button() {
  return (
   <>
    <button>TEST 1</button>
   </>
  );
}

export default Button;
```